# How do i reduce density of retopo?

Tags: modeling

So im retopologizing a sculpt i did and part of the mesh gets very dense but im not really sure how to reduce this without ruining the flow of it. i tired a method shown in the bottom pic but kind of guessed and im not sure if thats the best way to go about it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tris can be a solution if it doesn't cause any problem when you bend the object, you need to test it, here is another solution to go from 3 faces to 1:

[image]

Comment: sorry for such a late reply but i havent been able to implement this until recently and it helps a lot thank you!